# TextX retreiving object parent types

Tags: python, textx

Assume that we have two rules like this in our grammar:

```
Value: AttributeReference | PrimitiveValue;
PrimitiveValue: BoolValue | StringValue | IntValue;
```

I want to implement a code generator for this language. Basically, for each rule, I defined a function that does that. For example, `code_gen_value` function gets an object and if the type of the object is `AttributeReference` then it will call `code_gen_attribute_reference (passing the object)`, or if the type is `PrimitiveValue`, then it calls `code_gen_primitive_value (passing the object)`. The issue is that I am using the following to retrieve the type of the object:

```
value_type = cname(value) where:

def cname(o):
     return o.__class__.__name__
```

However, when I run it on an example, `the value_type` is `StringValue` in `code_gen_value function` for the input object. My question is, how can I check for the object to be a subtype of the `PrimitiveValue`?

In XTexnd, one could use `instanceof` keyword and actually `if obj instanceof PrimitiveValue` would work in the `code_gen_value`. I am wondering how we can express that in TextX.

Is there a way to refer to the types in the metamodel generated for our grammar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check if object is an instance of some type according to the inheritance specified by the textX grammar you can use [textx_isinstance](http://textx.github.io/textX/latest/model/#textx_isinstanceobj-cls). In the current release of textX (2.2.0) it can be imported from `textx.scoping.tools`. Starting from 2.3.0 it will be available in the `textx` module.

Comment: Thank you Igor! This is what I was looking for.